# pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle backward compatibility

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pickle

`pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle`'s compression parameter was introduced in pandas 0.20.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html

Before pandas 0.20, there was no compression param that I needed to specify.

I have a webapp written using pandas 0.18 and to read the pickle file using pandas.read_pickle in version 0.18 without error, how should I pickle the file?

So far I have tried setting the compression parameter to None and 'gzip'. Both don't work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't actually need to specify. The default `compression='infer'` should work.

But, why not just import and use pickle?

This is what I have been using

```
# import and save object as pickle
import pickle
pickle.dump(object, open('filename.pkl', 'wb'))

# and this is how to load them
loaded_object = pickle.load(open('filename.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But if you pickle it using pandas 0.20 (infer or any other setting) and open it in pandas 0.18, then you get error.

Comment: ohhh. Pickled objects are version sensitive. If you want to send and open a pickled object from one computer to another, you will need to ensure that the relevant libraries are the same.